# how to set layout_width and layout_height in GridLayout programmatically

Tags: android, layout, android-gridlayout

trying to set layout params but did not find any suitable method to set width and height as `wrap_content` programmatically. How to do this

```
public void populateGrid(){
            GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(this);
            //now here i want to set layout_width and layout_height as wrap_content 
            grid.setColumnCount(columnCount);
            for(int i=0; i<floors.size(); i++){
              ... 
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using `setLayoutParams()` method

```
grid.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```